# Can I deploy an Android .apk file on server?

Tags: android

I am trying to make the .apk file available to users. But, I don't want to go through app store. Now, my question is can we place the apk file on server? If yes, how? I tried to upload treating it like a war file and obviously it didn't work. Please suggest how to place it on server and access it. 
Thank you!

Comment: well you can put it on a server, and then the user downloads and installs on their phone. I think they would have to access link from their phone, have you tried that ?

Comment: Dropbox + public link

Comment: You need the APK to be signed unless you want the users going to settings>apps/security>unknown sources

Comment: I tried to upload to local tomcat server and it says the file has to be .war file. could you please let me know the steps to upload to server. Thanks!

Comment: That option has to be enabled regardless, whether the APK is signed or not. Only apps on the Play Store can be installed without that option being enabled.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM, you can sign it all you want, unless it comes from the play store, you still need to enable `unknown sources`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Upload the APK to your server or any storage online, even a Dropbox can do the job.
- Give the link of the APK to your users
- Users download it on their phone or tablet
- Users should have activated the installation from Unknown sources : Settings > Applications > Unknown sources...

Comment: Thanks Erowlin. How do i upload .apk to tomcat server?

Comment: Tomcat server is just a file system that is online for others persons. 
Here you may find your answer : http://serverfault.com/questions/143667/how-to-access-a-simple-file-or-folder-from-tomcat-webapps-folder

Answer (score -1):

You could also use [Hockeyapp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) or similar service to automatically distribute the application among users. You can find Hockeyapp's API documentation for uploading .apk files [here](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api/api-apps#upload-app).

Comment: The URL is not working!

Comment: HockeyApp has been retired.